# Search bar does not provide results

Tags: php, wpf

I'm trying to make a search bar. The problem is that is does not give me any results.

Here is my Controller:

```
 public function results(Request $request)
{
    $results = User::whereHas(function($query) use ($request){
        if(($id = $request->get("id"))){
            $query->where("id", $id);
        }

        if(($term = $request->get('term'))){
            $query->where('name','like','%'.$term.'%');
        }

    });
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/results', 'UserController@results')->name('results.index');
```

Here is my view:

```
{!! Form::open([ ['route'=>'results.index'],'method'=>'GET', 'role'=>'search','action'=>'UserController@results']) !!}

<div class="input-group">
{!! Form::text('term',Request::get('term'),['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Search...']) !!}

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Thanks in advance!